# AngularJS: Read route param from within controller

Tags: variables, angularjs, controller, routes, url-parameters

How can a parameter from an URL be read within an AngularJS controller?

Let's say I have an URL like `http://localhost/var/:value` and I want the value to be stored in a variable within the controller for the `/var/:value` URL.

I have tried using `$routeParams.value` and `$route.current.params.value` but `$routeParams` is undefined at the beginning and `$route` doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "$routeParams is undefined at the beginning and $route doesn't work"? Could you share code where you've tried to make them work? Both $route.current and $routeParams should give correct results in a controller provider that you've set up routes and injected dependencies into a controller.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you probably inject `$routeParams` or `$route` in a controller that is run before a route change has occurred, e.g. your main/master/page controller.

If you inject `$routeParams` in a controller for a specific route (specified by the `controller` property when you define the route), then it will work, otherwise you're probably better of listening to the various events the route service broadcasts.

Try to change your code to use

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, current, prev) {
   // ... 
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, the controller is run before a route change has occurred because the client is directly calling the URL when connecting.
But your posted code doesn't work because there's no route change. Any other suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: If your clients hits the url directly without you letting AngularJS handle the routing then you won't be able to use `$routeParams`. `$routeParams` only work if you're using `$routeProvider.when(/movies/:genre, { ... })`, otherwise you have to extract the values manually. Question: are you using AngularJS routing or are you simply looking for a way to extract values from the url?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS for routing because I want to load different `templateUrls` in my `ng-view` (angular-express-seed). But thanks for the answer, seems that I need to solve my problem with a different approach.

Comment: Had the same issue, I was trying to reference $route.current.controller and it was undefined in a controller on the "master" page before the actual ng-view route was populated.

Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Requirements: Ensure 'ngRoute' is in your app module

```
Route provider set up as: http://localhost/var/:valName
```

Function set up as:

```
function functionName($scope, $routeParams){$scope.value = $routeParams.valName;}
```

HTML view:

```
{{value['valName']}}
```