# Accessing routeparams from multiple controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my routes, I have it set up so that Controller1 gets called for the route '/:id' which controls one section of the page. However, I also need the :id route param in Controller2. How can I access that information in Controller2 as well?

I am using the $routeProvider service to access the route params in Controller1. This returns an empty object in Controller2.

EDIT:

I created a demo to illustrate my problem better. I want to access $routeParams from 2 controllers but it is only getting recognized by Controller2.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11600860/angular/index.html#/4445

If you look in the console, routeParams is only getting logged into the console by Controller2, not Controller1. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your demo no longer exists, but I had what sounds like a similar problem and found a related answer at [AngularJS: Read route param from within controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263409/angularjs-read-route-param-from-within-controller/16266601#16266601).  The general issue (in my case) was that `$routeParams` is not yet loaded when the controller initially loads and tries to access individual values.

To get around this, I was able to execute a controller method on `ng-init`, at which point I could successfully access any of the `$routeParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`$routeParams`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams) service, this should give you what you need. I'm currently injecting it into multiple controllers on a page and accessing the `:id` param as easily as `$routeParams.id`.

Comment: I did inject $routeParams into both controllers, but it only contains the params for the controller that is specified in my $routeProvider configuration. I need the params in another controller.

Comment: I made an edit to the original post to illustrate my problem w/ a demo.

Comment: That link isn't working for me, it just hangs. Can you set it up on jsfiddle, plunker, or jsbin?

Comment: no, i couldnt replicate the same behavior on one of those because i needed URL access

Comment: $routeParams also will not work for me in another controller, other then the one specified by $routeProvider. Still looking for a solution