# Pretty url with Angularjs/.htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, routes, friendly-url, route-provider

I've been struggling with this for a week now. I use Anguarjs and I set the html5mode(true) to get rid of the hash sign "#" that you needed in the url before.
Everything works fine amd my URL logic works with Query Parameters.

www.domain.com/thecurrentpage/?title=banana

And it changes and refresh the page when I click on something else and then it displays the right content.

I just want to be able to have a link like:

www.domain.com/thecurrentpage/banana

And come to the same page.
That actually will point you to the first one with query params.
I feels like I've tried everything in the .htaccess file with rewrite rules and everything with angular routing. I just don't get it.

Comment: what is `Angular 1` here

Comment: It is the $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); for removing the # sign. And I mention it to be sure that this doesn't affect the .htaccess file or the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the : syntax in your routing.

In your routing add a route like this:

```
/thecurrentpage/:title
```

Then you can use:

```
$routeParams.title
```

To get the value "banana"

This might help ... [AngularJS: Read route param from within controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263409/angularjs-read-route-param-from-within-controller)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.
When I paste www.domain.com/thecurrentpage/banana into the address field and press ENTER. Then I actually want to come to www.domain.com/thecurrentpage/index.html?title=banana
But now I come to www.domain.com/thecurrentpage/banana/index.html...which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, seems like my biggest problem with this was that I removed the Angular hashtag with html5Mode(true). Things started to make sense when I got it back since then, everything after the hashtag doesn't really count as index.html as I understand it. It is what you specify it to do. I have to remove the hashtag in the .htaccess file instead I suppose.